# Ant Design Table which is both sortable and editable

Tags: javascript, antd

I'm trying to create an Ant.Design table which is both sortable and editable. The Ant.Design docs show sample code of both ([here](https://ant.design/components/table/?locale=en-US#components-table-demo-edit-row) and [here](https://ant.design/components/table/?locale=en-US#components-table-demo-head)). I tried to combine these in a minimal code repository here: https://github.com/Silox/Ant-Design--EditableSortableTable.

The main problem is that the table gets reordered while editing a value and I haven't found a way to prevent this. The behaviour I am looking for is that when a user edits a cell, the ordering is put "on hold", and when the user is done editing, the table is resorted. Would anyone have any idea to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

- Add a boolean state `editing` to `EditableSortableTable`.
- Set it in `setEditable/setNotEditable` to `isEditableMap.length > 0`.
- for `EditableSortableTable` add:

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !(nextState.editing && this.state.editing)
}`

**[update]** Given the requirement to *not* use `shouldComponentUpdate()` you can introduce a new `_sortTitle` prop on the table objects and sort the rows based on this prop. This prop is not rendered, but is set to `title` when mounting, and then updated only once edit of a title cell is complete.

Comment: Hi @jesper-we, thanks for your comment. I like this approach if the edit action would be the only action for this component, but in my broader use case the component should be able to do things concurrent to editing one row (e.g. editing multiple rows or even modifying data from outside the component, so the data in the component immediately updates). Overwriting the shouldComponentUpdate like this would prevent all those actions, unless I specifically add an exception for each action.

Comment: Perhaps I should take a closer at a custom trigger-sort-function where I decide to resort or not based on the `editing` boolean.

Comment: I updated my answer with a second approach that I actually wrote originally, but then removed because it was less elegant than the shouldComponentUpdate approach :-)

Comment: But then the table rows switch position when you click edit in a sorted table, which also is a bit annoying.

Comment: Ok, so this means <Table> resorts from scratch on each update. I thought it was smarter and did it incrementally :-)

Comment: Yes, that's works great! I also had to change the changeValue() function to update the record regardless of it's index (as this index didn't correspond to the source data after sorting). I also added a bounty which I can award tomorrow and I've pushed the completed code to the sample repo :) Thanks!

Comment: Very kind of you sir ;-)